# Why value of JSON changes “:” to “=” in Helper class

Tags: java, handlebars.js, handlebars.java

The template is created in Handlebars JS. and to process in Java  jknack handlebars is used. I wrote helper class to assign value in a variable through enum syntax. I got inspiration from enum `NumberHelper` and write my own enum `VarHelper`. Here is the "Var" code

```
{{ var "$a" jsonObj }}

var { 
@Override public CharSequence safeApply(final String variableName, final Options options) throws IOException { 
  System.out.println( options.params[0]); options.context.data(variableName, options.params[0]); return null; 
} 
};
```

I expect `options.params[0]` value should be `{name : john}`, but the actual output is `{name=john}`

Comment: Looks like default `toString()` method implementation, try to override it.

Comment: @Eugene which object's toString method will be modified?

Comment: The one that is referenced by `options.params[0]`.